# Method is non static and cannot be referenced

Tags: java

At the end when creating the recipe entered by the user I am getting an error because i added a method addInstructions. The error is that it is non static and cannot be referenced. I have run into this error before and i usually just change it from `void` to `static` and it fixes it.

Can the community kindly take a look and give me some advice? The goal is for the Array Recipe instructions is to be added as well. The error occurs at the creation of `recipe_1`.

```
public class Recipe_MAIN {
   
    public String recipeName;
    private int servings;
    ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> recipeIngredients = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> recipeInstructions;
    private double totalRecipeCalories;
    
    // Creating accessors and mutators for the instance variables
    /**
     * 
     * @param recipeName 
     */
    public void setRecipeName(String recipeName){
        this.recipeName = recipeName;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @return recipeName
     */
    public String getRecipeName(){
        return recipeName;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param servings 
     */
    
    public void setServings(int servings){
        this.servings = servings;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @return servings
     */
    public int getServings(){
        return servings;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param recipeIngredients 
     */
    
    public void setRecipeIngredients(ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> recipeIngredients){
        this.recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @return 
     */
    public ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> getRecipeIngredients(){
        return recipeIngredients;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param recipeInstructions 
     */
     public void setRecipeInstructions(ArrayList<String> recipeInstructions) {
        this.recipeInstructions = recipeInstructions;
    }
     /**
      * 
      * @return 
      */
    public ArrayList<String> getRecipeInstructions() {
        return recipeInstructions;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param totalRecipeCalories 
     */
    
    public void setTotalRecipeCalories(int totalRecipeCalories){
        this.totalRecipeCalories = totalRecipeCalories;
    }
    public double getTotalRecipeCalories(){
        return totalRecipeCalories;
    }
    
    // Now we build the constructors one to create a new object and one to overload the constructor
    
    public Recipe_MAIN(){
        this.recipeName = "";
        this.servings = 0;
        this.recipeIngredients = new ArrayList();
        this.recipeInstructions = new ArrayList();
        this.totalRecipeCalories = 0;
        
    }
    
  public Recipe_MAIN(String recipeName, int servings,ArrayList<String>       recipeInstructions, ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> recipeIngredients, double totalRecipeCalories){
        this.recipeName = recipeName;
        this.servings = servings;
        this.recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients;
        this.recipeInstructions = recipeInstructions;
        this.totalRecipeCalories = totalRecipeCalories;
    }
    public void addInstructions() {
        
        String instruction = "";
        
        boolean addMoreInstructions = true;
                
                Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        do {
                    System.out.println("Please enter an instruction or type 'end' if you are finished entering instructions: ");
            instruction = scnr.nextLine();
                
            if (instruction.toLowerCase().equals("end")) {
                                    
                    addMoreInstructions = false;
                    
                    } 
            else {
                            recipeInstructions.add(instruction);
                                        
                            addMoreInstructions = true;
                    }
                        
        } while (addMoreInstructions == true);              
    }
    
    
    // Print recipe method 
    public void printRecipe(){
        double singleServingCalories = (totalRecipeCalories / servings);
        System.out.println("Here is the information associated with you recipe: ");
        System.out.println("Recipe: "+ recipeName);
        System.out.println("This recipe serves: "+ servings);
        System.out.println("These are the ingredients you entered: "+ recipeIngredients);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < recipeIngredients.size(); i++) {  //For loop to print each array member
            Ingredient_MAIN ingredient = recipeIngredients.get(i);
            System.out.println(ingredient.getNameOfIngredient());
        }
         System.out.println("Each Serving Has " + singleServingCalories + " Calories.");
    
    }  
    
    public static Recipe_MAIN addNewRecipe(){
        double totalRecipeCalories = 0;
        ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> recipeIngredients = new ArrayList();
        
        
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the recipe: ");
        String recipeName = scnr.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of servings for this recipe: ");
        int servings = Integer.parseInt(scnr.nextLine());
        
        
        // Using a do,While loop to add more ingreadients like in Stepping stone 4
        
        //do{
          while(true){  
            
            System.out.println("Please enter the ingredient name or type 'end' if you are finished: ");
            String ingredientName = scnr.nextLine();
            
            
                if(ingredientName.toLowerCase().equals("end")){
                    //addMoreIngredients = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please Enter the Unit of measurement for this Ingredient, Please only select from the following options: ");
                    System.out.println("Cups, Tbsp, Tsp, Grams");
                    String unitMeasurement = "";
                        while(true){
                            unitMeasurement = scnr.nextLine();
                            if ((unitMeasurement.equalsIgnoreCase("Cups")) || (unitMeasurement.equalsIgnoreCase("Tbsp")) || (unitMeasurement.equalsIgnoreCase("Tsp")) || (unitMeasurement.equalsIgnoreCase("Grams"))){
                                System.out.println("You have selected " + unitMeasurement);
                                break;
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Please enter one of the preceding options.");
                            }
                        }
                        
                     System.out.println("Please enter the number of units of " + ingredientName + " required (between 1 and 100): ");
                     
                     float ingredientAmount;
                     while(true){
                         ingredientAmount = Float.parseFloat(scnr.nextLine());
                         
                         if ((ingredientAmount >= 1)&& (ingredientAmount <= 100)){
                             System.out.println("The amount you entered " + ingredientAmount + " is a valid amount!");
                             break;
                         } else if (ingredientAmount < 1) {
                             System.out.println(ingredientAmount + " is less than 1, sorry you are out of attempts.");
                         } else {
                             System.out.println(ingredientAmount + " is greater than 100, sorry you are out of attempts.");
                         }
                     }
                     
                    
                    System.out.println("Please enter the calories per unit of the ingredient " + ingredientName + " (between 1 and 2000 calories): ");
                    int numberOfCaloriesPerUnit;
                    while(true){
                       numberOfCaloriesPerUnit = Integer.parseInt(scnr.nextLine()); 
                       
                       if ((numberOfCaloriesPerUnit >=1 )&& (numberOfCaloriesPerUnit <= 2000)){
                           System.out.println(numberOfCaloriesPerUnit + " is a valid number of calories!");
                           break;
                       } else if (numberOfCaloriesPerUnit < 1){
                           System.out.println(numberOfCaloriesPerUnit + " is less than 1. Sorry, you are out of attempts."); 
                       } else {
                           System.out.println(numberOfCaloriesPerUnit + " is greater than 2000. Sorry, you are out of attempts.");
                       }
                    }
                       
                       float totalCalories = ingredientAmount * numberOfCaloriesPerUnit;
                       
                       System.out.println(ingredientName + " uses " + ingredientAmount + " number of " + unitMeasurement + "'s" + " which contains " + totalCalories + " total calories.");
                       System.out.println("Ingredient has been successfully added.");
                       
                        Ingredient_MAIN ing = new Ingredient_MAIN(ingredientName, unitMeasurement,ingredientAmount, numberOfCaloriesPerUnit, totalCalories);
                            recipeIngredients.add(ing);
                            totalRecipeCalories += totalCalories;
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    
                }
            
      
  
        
        Recipe_MAIN recipe1 = new Recipe_MAIN(recipeName, servings,recipeInstructions, recipeIngredients, totalRecipeCalories);
        recipe1.printRecipe();
        return recipe1;
    }
```

Comment: may you try `public static void`?

Comment: I was also wondering if i can skip the addInstructions method and just add the logic in the print recipe method

Comment: I mean, yes you could do that. I won't say it's a good idea; splitting your code in functions and modules is a well known good practice (in any language). By the way would you show where are you trying to call the `addInstructions` method?

Comment: @LukaCerrutti i tried this but then recipeInstructions.add(instruction) will not be able to be refrenced

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to use this method using an instance of the class. It should not be static then. Simply `public void`. would you mind sharing a screenshot or the text of the error you're getting when executing this function at that instance?

Comment: @LukaCerrutti currently i am not calling on it anywhere i want to in my main method, my program will list a menu for the user to select from and based on that selection , so for example in the print recipe method the instructions will also be printed along with the recipe details

Comment: @LukaCerrutti  non-static variable recipeInstructions cannot be referenced from a static context

constructor Recipe_MAIN in class Recipe_MAIN cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found:    String,int,ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN>,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
----
This occurs at :      Recipe_MAIN recipe1 = new Recipe_MAIN(recipeName, servings,recipeInstructions, recipeIngredients, totalRecipeCalories);
    recipe1.printRecipe();
    return recipe1;

Comment: Ok, seems you're sending the parameters in wrong order. You're doing `Recipe_MAIN(recipeName, servings, recipeInstructions, recipeIngredients, totalRecipeCalories);` but recipeInstructions and recipeIngredients should be inverted, like `Recipe_MAIN(recipeName, servings, recipeIngredients, recipeInstructions, totalRecipeCalories);`. The fact you're sending wrong parameters order make java think you're referencing the first non-parameter constructor and then telling you your parameter list differ in length. You can also go to the overload of the constructor and change the order of params there.

Comment: Submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the parameters when initializing the `Recipe_MAIN recipe1` is wrong.

You are doing:

```
Recipe_MAIN recipe1 = new Recipe_MAIN(recipeName, servings,recipeInstructions, recipeIngredients, totalRecipeCalories);
```

Meanwhile, the constructor is:

```
public Recipe_MAIN(String recipeName, int servings, ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> recipeIngredients,ArrayList<String> recipeInstructions, double totalRecipeCalories)
```

`recipeIngredients` and `recipeInstructions` are in wrong order. You may want to change them either in the constructor or in the `recipe1` definition.

Comment: Maybe i am not understanding, but i switched the order in the constructor but the new error is non-static variable recipeInstructions cannot be referenced from a static context

incompatible types: ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>
----    but i am not trying to convert only include

Comment: Can you post your updated code @ThatGuy?

Comment: just did but the error is an odd one in Recipe_MAIN i get "non-static variable recipeInstructions cannot be referenced from a static context

incompatible types: ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>
----"   and in RecipeBox_MAIN i get "constructor Recipe_MAIN in class Recipe_MAIN cannot be applied to given types;
  required: String,int,ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN>,double
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

The assigned value is never used
----"

Comment: try changing `ArrayList<String> recipeInstructions;` to `private static ArrayList<String> recipeInstructions = new ArrayList();`. Same with `ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> recipeIngredients = new ArrayList();` to `private static ArrayList<Ingredient_MAIN> recipeIngredients = new ArrayList();`.